# Unable to run nginx as a specified user

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx from source. I did following steps to configure it.

```
tar -xvf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz

cd nginx-1.8.0/

./configure --prefix=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx --sbin-path=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/logs/nginx.pid --error-log-path=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/logs/error.log --http-log-path=/home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/logs/access.log

make

sudo make install
```

After these steps I started nginx.  It ran successfully. I got the following results:

```
root     13928  1385  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/sbin/nginx
nobody   13929 13928  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                   
jegan    13934 10653  0 10:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

When I change the user name of the worker process to `mass` in the `user` directive in the `nginx.conf` file I get the following error

```
nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("mass") failed in /home/jegan/nginx-1.8.0/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:2
```

Why did I get this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the specified user didn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that there is no user named `mass` on the system.

Comment: thank you womble. i want to run the worker process as mass. what should i do? I am new to nginx. I don't know anything

Comment: You probably want to create a user named `mass`.

Comment: If there is no user named mass, then i will create the user named mass. thats ok.  If there is a user name as jegan, i want to run the worker process as jegan instead of nobody the default user name . For this what should i do? sorry for my english. i am poor in english

Comment: If you want to run the nginx workers as `jegan`, you should set the value of the `user` parameter to be `jegan`.

Comment: I should change the user name of workers into jegan in the user directive. Am i right? Can i change the username of Master process ?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  No, the username of the master process will always stay as the user that nginx was started as.